# How can I use back references with `grep` in R?

Tags: r, regex

I am looking for an elegant way of returning back references using regular expressions in R.  Le me explain:

Let's say I want to find strings that start with a month name:

```
x <- c("May, 1, 2011", "30 June 2011")
grep("May|^June", x, value=TRUE)
[1] "May, 1, 2011"
```

This works, but I really want to isolate the month (i.e. "May", not the entire matched string.

So, one can use `gsub` to return the back reference using the `substitute` parameter.  But this has two problems:

1. You have to wrap the pattern inside ".*(pattern).*)" so that the substitution occurs on the entire string.
2. Rather than returning NA for non-matched strings, `gsub` returns the original string. This is clearly not what I desire:

The code and results:

```
gsub(".*(^May|^June).*", "\\1", x) 
[1] "May"          "30 June 2011"
```

I could probably code a workaround by doing all kinds of additional checks, but this quickly becomes very messy.

To be crystal clear, the desired results should be:

```
[1] "May"          NA
```

Is there an easy way of achieving this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `stringr` package has a function exactly for this purpose:

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("May, 1, 2011", "30 June 2011", "June 2012")
str_extract(x, "May|^June")
# [1] "May"  NA     "June"
```

It's a fairly thin wrapper around `regexpr`, but `stringr` generally makes string handling easier by being more consistent than base R functions.

Comment: Thanks, Hadley. I am a big fan of stringr in general. I have no idea why I didn't think of searching there first.  D'oh.

Answer (score 20):

`regexpr` is similar to `grep`, but returns the position and length of the (first) match in each string:

```
> x <- c("May, 1, 2011", "30 June 2011", "June 2012")
> m <- regexpr("May|^June", x)
> m
[1]  1 -1  1
attr(,"match.length")
[1]  3 -1  4
```

This means that the first string had a match of length 3 staring at position 1, the second string had no match, and the third string had a match of length 4 at position 1.

To extract the matches, you could use something like:

```
> m[m < 0] = NA
> substr(x, m, m + attr(m, "match.length") - 1)
[1] "May"  NA     "June"
```

Comment: Great suggestion, thank you. In the end, I decided to accept Hadley's answer, simply because it is more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

The gsubfn package is more general than the grep and regexpr functions and has ways for you to return the backrefrences, see the strapply function.

Comment: Try this: `library(gsubfn); strapply(x, "^(May|June)")` .